# stringstream problem - vector iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, stl, stringstream

I've got a problem with the following code snippet.

It is related to the stringstream "stringstream css(cv.back())" bit. If it is commented out the program will run ok.

It is really weird, as I keep getting it in some of my programs, but if I just create a console project the code will run fine. In some of my Win32 programs it will and in some it won't (then it will return "vector iterator not dereferencable" but it will compile just fine).

Any ideas at all would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
vector<double> cRes(2);
vector<double> pRes(2);

int readTimeVects2(vector<double> &cRes, vector<double> &pRes){
    string segments;
    vector<string> cv, pv, chv, phv;
    ifstream cin("cm.txt");
    ifstream pin("pw.txt");
    ifstream chin("hm.txt");
    ifstream phin("hw.txt");

    while (getline(cin,segments,'\t')) {
        cv.push_back(segments);
    }

    while (getline(pin,segments,'\t')) {
        pv.push_back(segments);
    }

    while (getline(chin,segments,'\t')) {
        chv.push_back(segments);
    }

    while (getline(phin,segments,'\t')) {
        phv.push_back(segments);
    }

    cin.close();  
    pin.close();  
    chin.close();   
    phin.close();

    stringstream phss(phv.front());
    phss >> pRes[0];
    phss.clear();
    stringstream chss(chv.front());
    chss >> cRes[0];
    chss.clear();

    stringstream pss(pv.back());
    pss >> pRes[1];
    pss.clear();
    stringstream css(cv.back());
    css >> cRes[1];
    css.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure `cv` is not empty?

Comment: you need to explain a bit more. what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Not addressing your question, but this should really be refactored. You have basically identical code you are calling four times with different names.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues here. Either or both of these problems can be causing the issue you are experiencing.

**You are hiding names from outside your scope**:

```
vector<double> cRes(2);
vector<double> pRes(2);

int readTimeVects2(vector<double> &cRes, vector<double> &pRes){
```

cRes and pRes are going to be the variables passed to your function, not the global variables you have demonstrated.

You need to show us the calling code where the issue occurs before we will be able to diagnose this problem -- though I wonder why you're not just using push_back here,

---

There's another problem here:

```
stringstream phss(phv.front());
stringstream chss(chv.front());
stringstream pss(pv.back());
stringstream css(cv.back());
```

**You have no checking to ensure phv, chv, pv, and cv are not empty**. It's entirely possible your `std::getline`s above had problems that prevented them from completing successfully, and it's also entirely possible that the files you passed were empty.

Comment: @Billy He's also sneaked a "cin" in there, to add to the confusion :-)

Comment: Solved - thanks Billy. It was a problem of some files being empty/non-existent (I had moved things around when trying to link statically, I thought I had double-checked that, but I must have missed an odd file or two). 

I am not too concerned with error checking as the program will not be distributed and will receive fixed-size txt files (but I can see why one ought to be doing it).

Thanks a million!